# No Libraries option under WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I want to include jQuery in my Libraries for code completion, but there is no Libraries under JavaScript.

[image: No Libraries option under WebStorm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to include jQuery in my Libraries for code completion, but there is no Libraries under JavaScript.

That's because you are accessing the wrong settings.

**You need "File | Settings"** (Windows/Linux; on Mac it's "WebStorm | Preferences") which show global + this project settings ... but on screenshot **you are using "File | Default Settings"** ... which affect only future new projects and do not contain all possible settings pages.